# docker-machine on windows 10 - "You must have a copy of the scp binary locally to use the scp feature"

Tags: powershell, docker, scp, docker-for-windows

I am using command :
docker-machine scp manager:/home/docker/foo.txt .

however, Windows PowerShell return "You must have a copy of the scp binary locally to use the scp feature".

I am sure I have install 'docker for windows' & ' docker toolbox'. So what should I do?

Comment: I have the same problem but I can't find any solutions, but "wget" command is available in the virtual machine created by "docker-machine", you can use Tomcat or Nginx to map file to http url, that works but not perfect

Comment: I had this same issue using **Visual Studio Code** (as administrator) on **Windows 10**.  Use **Git Bash** (as administrator).

Comment: I used Docker Toolbox and Docker Quickstart Terminal(it should be based on Git bash), it does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also faced similar issue on Windows 8.1. I used Git Bash(in Administrator mode) instead of Powershell to resolve it.

Comment: How did you run docker-machine from bash? I get a "command not found" error.

Comment: Well, I didn't do anything special to run docker-machine from bash,it just worked. But, I already had git-bash installed on my machine before I installed docker.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to get around this problem, why not solve it directly?

Most probably, you already have `scp.exe` on your machine if you have **Git Bash** installed, so all you need to do is add the folder where `scp.exe` is located to your `PATH` environment variable.

In my case `scp.exe` was located in `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`

That solved the same issue for me

Comment: Thanks, this kept me in PowerShell. I love bash, just not on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to have [Git for Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) installed, `docker-machine scp` will run successfully in Git Bash.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue using **Visual Studio Code** version 1.14.0 (as administrator) on *Windows 10*. Use **Git Bash** (as administrator).

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by using the Putty scp program called pscp.exe that I already had installed.

(initially I tried to rename 'pscp' to 'scp', but that doesn't work because docker engine uses the -o option to send SSH commands.  'pscp' doesn't have the -o option.)

You can use pscp on the command line directly.  First find out the IP address of the VM:

```
docker-machine env <VM_name>
```

VM name in your case is 'manager'.  Take the ip address (without port) out of the $Env:DOCKER_HOST variable.  Eg:

```
$Env:DOCKER_HOST = "tcp://192.168.XXX.XXX:2376"
```

Then use pscp to send the file:

```
pscp <file_to_send> docker@<ip_address_of_VM>:/home/docker/foo.txt
```

You will be prompted for the password of the 'docker' user.  I found that docker uses a default password '**tcuser**' which worked when I did it.